No puedo hacer scroll a mis elementos en ionic con sass
estoy desarrollando una app en ionic y tengo una parte que contiene 7 cards algo como esto:

    <div class="cards-container">
        <ion-card *ngFor="let daycard of days" class="cards">
          <ion-card-content class="card-content">
            <div class="image-day">
              <img src="{{ daycard.image }}" alt="">
            </div>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </div>


queria hacer que de esos 7 cards solo fueran visibles 4 y los demas se ocultaran y meter un scroll horizontal para poder ver las cards restantes, he podido hacer que se oculten las demas y que aprezca el scroll pero al momento de intentar desplazarme no funciona el scroll.
mi scss:

    .cards-container {
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        background-color: #2C2C2E;
        padding: 10px;
        gap: 10px;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      
        .cards {
          flex: 0 0 auto;
          min-width: 300px;
          background-color: #2C2C2E;
          scroll-snap-align: start;
      
          .card-content {
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: auto;
      
            .image-day {
              width: 100%;
              height: 200px;
      
              img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }


alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor
